# loop over variable that is regular expression in r

Tags: r, regex

I am searching for files in a folder by using a regular expression, such as:

```
for(i in c('exp\\d_baseline', 'exp\\d_treatment', 'control\\d_baseline', 'control\\d_treatment'){
file.list <- dir(file_path, pattern = i, full.names = T)

# ...irrelevant manipulation on these files here (concatenation)

output_name <- paste0(i, '_concat.csv')
}
```

This gives me filenames with the \ from the pattern detection. How can I remove the \'s when specifying my output filenames?

Comment: You can use sub i.e. `paste0(sub("\\d", "", i, fixed = TRUE), "_concat.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

One option is `sub` with `fixed = TRUE` before applying the `paste`

```
output_name <- paste0(sub("\\d", "", i, fixed = TRUE), "_concat.csv")
```